# How to get last redirect page content with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the content of a url. The exact url is dynamic, but I have the url that redirects to the final url with the data. Everything is fine when I type this url into the browser, but when the following curl config is not getting any data back. What else can I try? Thanks!

```
// custom curl to get page content of last redirect
function getCurlContent($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
if ($content===FALSE)
    echo curl_error($ch);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

echo output:

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chainSSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateSSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Comment: You've got a typo and are missing a `'` in the CURLOPT_URL line, but even with that, `'$var'` is going to use `$`, `v`, `a`, and `r` as the url, because `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** expand varaibles. You just want `$url` by itself. no quotes needed. using `"$var"` would fix the problem, but is a major symtom of cargo-cult programming, so don't do that.

Comment: Good catch! but that was a typo I entered into stackoverflow... let me fix it

Comment: did you check if $content is a boolean false? that'd indicate curl failed, and you should check `curl_error()` for details.

Comment: Good call! Tried that... and this is what i got: "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chainSSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateSSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain". any idea what to do now?

Comment: quick/dirty, turn off curl's ssl cert verification stuff. proper fix: get a CA list to install for curl. it used to ship with one, but hasn't for a long time, so by default it won't accept ANY cert as valid.